# How to test three-phase transformer's rated kVA

Tags: transformer, three-phase

I work as an electrical quality engineer at the borders. I test electrical transformers, and the government takes tax money according to the capacity rated kVA of the electric transformer.

We discovered that merchants change the nameplate of the transformer with one that shows a lower-capacity kVA, so that less money is paid for the tax, because for higher-capacity kVA the merchant pays more money for the tax. Then after crossing the border, they change the nameplate to the original nameplate of the electric transformer.

So I want a way to test the real capacity rated kVA of the transformer, or test the voltage and current so that I can calculate it from the apparent power law. Is there a device or method for testing the rated kVA?

[image: transformer nameplate]

[image: transformer nameplate]

Comment: Welcome! What information on the transformer do you have?

Comment: What do you want to test? Insulation? continuity? ratios?

Comment: Have you tried contacting the supplier?

Comment: Sounds like you would need a 250 or 400kW load and a 11kV supply of 13.1A or 21.5A respectively to *ensure* operation.  Manufacturer should have already tested this (how could they sell a product which did not meet its label)... ask them for the test data.

Comment: If you don't trust your suppliers to deliver you a tested and working unit, it's probably better to source new suppliers.

Comment: @greybeard - Thanks for trying to help, but please avoid answering in comments. That is [not an allowed use of comments](/help/privileges/comment) for several reasons. || The question has been reopened, so you can post an actual answer if you want to answer the question :) Thanks

Comment: @greybeard - Hi, Re: "*The question was closed when I commented.*" I know! Posting a comment-answer on a closed question, to bypass it being closed, is even worse. That is deliberate site abuse i.e. deliberately bypassing the site quality control mechanism of questions being closed (therefore not eligible to be answered) until they are deemed suitable. Please *do not* be tempted to do that. || I realise you're enthusiastic to add your knowledge. I have been tempted that way many times. But a large part of the SE quality control is by not answering poor-quality (e.g. closed) question. Thanks.

Comment: A suggestion that you probably don't have the power to implement, but that you might bring up to your superiors: Start requiring tamperproof nameplates. Some kind of sticker you can put on the side of the nameplate that leaves hard-to-remove residue when the nameplate is removed, or (a more invasive change that manufacturers are likely to push back against) riveted nameplates instead of screwed-on. While people will still find ways to circumvent this, as long as you can make it more trouble to avoid taxes than to simply pay them, most people will pay.

Answer (score 0):

Idea: It's pointless to cheat on the voltage.
Use DC sources to push primary&secondary rated currents.
If temperature rise isn't anywhere near \$\frac{P_{Cu}}{P_{Cu}\ \ +\ P_{Fe}}\$ the range quoted, something is off.

Comment: You may need to approximate installation/deheating recommendations closely.

Answer (score 0):

It's too easy for the importers to cheat, they may declare any small power rating specifying low temperature rise, large oversize for reliability and so on, plenty of good reasons

In my opinion the simple and fair way is to tax transformers by the weight.
Their nominal power is strongly correlated.

So it all boils down to changing the rules, it may be anything from plain sailing or just impossible depending on your own country rules.

Otherwise, the same thing from a different point of view more specifically addressing the question.

Prepare a look-up table from reputable manufacturers datasheet for different type of transformers.
The need to have the legal power to enforce this table to unwilling importers however remanins.

Comment: While I'm not concerned about favouring amorphous steel, doesn't this cause unwanted effects in Al vs. Cu, air vs. oil? (tax max. *losses*?)

Comment: Yes @greybeard weight is just related to power but of course there may be many "details" changing the fact. I still belive it is by far the simplest thing, it may be tuned preparing a lookup table for different type of transformers